# Why I can't use windows.resizable(False,False) when the window.geometry is (1200x900)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make my application not resizable. I found out that I can use window.resizable(False,False).

this is the code:

```
   import tkinter as tk
   from tkinter import ttk

    def login_admin_page():
     # create the main window
     window = tk.Tk()
     window.geometry("1200x900")


     # create two frames side by side
     frame1 = tk.Frame(window, width=600, height=900, bg="#D9D9D9")
     frame2 = tk.Frame(window, width=600, height=900, bg="#F0AFAF")

     frame1.pack(side="left")
     frame2.pack(side="right")

     # add a label to frame1 with the specified properties
     label = tk.Label(frame1, text="Admin Panel", font=("Inter", 24, "normal"), bg="#D9D9D9",        fg="black", justify="left")
     label.place(x=20, y=20, width=146, height=27)

     # set the line height to 29 pixels and vertical alignment to top
     label.config(anchor="nw", pady=0, padx=0, wraplength=0, height=0, width=0)

     # add a label and text area to frame1 for Username
     user_label = tk.Label(frame1, text="Username", font=("Inter", 18, "normal"), bg="#D9D9D9",  fg="black", justify="left")
     user_label.place(x=20, y=300, width=123, height=24)
     user_entry = tk.Entry(frame1, font=("Inter", 18, "normal"), bg="white", fg="black", justify="left")
     user_entry.place(x=153, y=300, width=200, height=28)

     # add a label and text area to frame1 for Password
     pass_label = tk.Label(frame1, text="Password", font=("Inter", 18, "normal"), bg="#D9D9D9", fg="black", justify="left")
     pass_label.place(x=20, y=350, width=123, height=24)
     pass_entry = tk.Entry(frame1, show="*", font=("Inter", 18, "normal"), bg="white", fg="black", justify="left")
     pass_entry.place(x=153, y=350, width=200, height=28)

     # add a login button to frame1
     login_button = tk.Button(frame1, text="Login", font=("Inter", 12), bg="#D9D9D9", fg="black",
                             bd=0, highlightthickness=0, activebackground="#B3B3B3",
                             command=lambda: print("Login button clicked"))
     login_button.place(x=200, y=450, width=82, height=24)

     # add a back button to frame1
     login_button = tk.Button(frame1, text="Back", font=("Inter", 12), bg="#D9D9D9", fg="black",
                             bd=0, highlightthickness=0, activebackground="#B3B3B3",
                             command=lambda: print("Back button clicked"))
     login_button.place(x=20, y=700, width=82, height=24)

     window.resizable(False, False)  # not resizable in both direction


     # run the main loop
     window.mainloop()

    login_admin_page()
```

I have tried to change the geometry of the windows and is working. But I need to have the geometry(1200x900).

Comment: Please use a minimum reproducible example. It helps others read your code better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. For example, does the problem still occur if we don't create the labels and buttons? If we simplify them? Are their specific positions relevant to causing the problem? What if there aren't any frames?

Comment: "If change the window.geometry smaller like( 250x600 is working), but with(1200,900) is not working" Can you find any other sizes that make it not work? If you experiment, can you figure out any rules about what the size needs to be for it to work or not work?

Comment: @Costache Alin: What's your question, you are talking about fullscreen and _If change the window.geometry smaller like(250x600 is working), but with(1200,900) is not working_

Comment: @MauriceMeyer the question is how to make a non-fullscreen window that is not resizable and keeps the specified size. OP claims that specifying a geometry of `"1200x900"` resulted in a very small window instead of one with the expected dimensions, and separately that trying to control the size using `minsize` and `maxsize` resulted in a window that could be fullscreened (which is also not desirable).

Comment: FYI: Your code works fine under MacOS, I cant resize the window and there is not fullscreen button.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in Windows 11 with Python 3.11.2.

Comment: That's nice to hear that. I will try another IDE. But, just to be sure, I want to be clear one more time. If I am running the application without the window.resizable(False,False) my window look as I want, with all the labels, button etc. If I am adding the window.resizable(False, False), the windows become small and I can't see a thing. Just the Admin panel label and the background colour. I am also using MacOS.

Comment: OH god, I have tried on my windows now. Is working. I am running Python 3.11 on MacOS and python 3.10 on windows.

Comment: Works on Kubuntu 22.10 with Python 3.10.7.